# Can you test for a player with a certain score in a certain area

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm making a dead by daylight map in Minecraft: Bedrock Edition and I was wondering if there is a way to test if a player in a certain area has a certain score because I made vaulting with `/tp @p[scores{alive=1}] ~ ~ ~` so I want to make it so only survivors who have alive 1 can do generators

Answer (score 1):

You can use the volume selector and scores selector

I am a java player but the volume selector's format should be very similar (x=,dx=,y=,dy=,z=,dz=).

`x=`,`y=`,`z=` refer to the starting coordinate of the block region, while `dx=`,`dy=`,`dz=` embodies the displacment of the coordinates required to draw a volume.
#note that dx dy and dz is not the end point coordinates, the end point coordinates should be `(x+dx,y+dy,z+dz)`

Suppose the "certain area" you are referring to is a box area of 10 meters side length at the spawn point (x=0,y=0,z=0)

`execute as @a[x=0,dx=10,y=0,dy=10,z=0,dz=10,scores={Alive:1}] run *insert code*`
This would run the inserted code for players meeting both requirements --- within the block region and have the score {Alive:1}

An alternative option:
Set an marker entity or armor stand at your "certain area" and
`execute as @e[type=marker,tag=area_marker] at @s run execute as @a[r=10,scores={Alive:1}] at @s run *insert code*`
Allows you to run the command without specifying coordinates which is convenient for mulitple placements.

Answer (score -1):

So for you to sense if someone is in a certain area , you can use [volume selectors](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Target_selectors#Selecting_targets_by_volume), `dx`, `dy`, and `dz`. The selected volume would be the space from `x`, `y`, and `z` to `x+dx`, `y+dy`, and `z+dz`. For example:

`/give @a[x=1, y=2, z=3, dx=2, dy=2, dz=2] cake`

This give anyone between `1 2 3` and `3 4 5` a cake

For the [score selector](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Target_selectors#Selecting_targets_by_scores), you almost did it, but not quite. The only thing you had to change is put an equal sign(`=`) between the `scores` and the `{Alive=1}`.

I can't really say the final command because I don't know your space which your testing players for.

Comment: 2 things. 1: Your answer doesn't provide any new information. 2: Your statement "This give anyone between 1 2 3 and 3 4 5 a cake." is both incorrect and unclear. You don't specify X Y or Z with these numbers. Also, if you meant X and Z this is incorrect as it would only affect players in Y 2-4.